# Using matplotlib's patches in julia

Tags: matplotlib, julia

Using the output from a computation in julia (working in IJulia), I'd like to draw a figure using matplotlib's patches module (via Steven Johnson's `PyCall` and `PyPlot` packages). I've read several related posts on stackoverflow, but I can't seem to get a minimum working example. Could somebody post a simple example? Say something that plots a rectangle or an ellipse?

Here's a python example that works:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
import matplotlib.pyplot
import matplotlib.patches

cfig = matplotlib.pyplot.figure()
c = cfig.add_subplot(111)
c.set_aspect("equal")
p = matplotlib.patches.Circle([0.5,0.5],0.40,fc="blue",ec="red",linewidth=5,zorder=0)
c.add_patch(p)

cfig.savefig("circle.pdf",bbox_inches="tight")
```

My attempt at the same thing in Julia stalls at the subplot

```
using PyPlot
using PyCall
@pyimport matplotlib.patches as patches

cfig = figure()
c = cfig.add_subplot(111)
```

Which yields:

```
type Figure has no field add_subplot
while loading In[19], in expression starting on line 4
```

Comment: Does the [PyPlot.jl Basic Usage example](https://github.com/stevengj/PyPlot.jl#basic-usage) work for you?

Comment: See [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/julia-users/pyplot%7Csort:date/julia-users/m7AQ_f_3lsk/FAj0gJOuftgJ) You need `cfig[:add_subplot]` syntax at this point.

Comment: @rickhg12hs. Yes, the basic example works for me.

Comment: @jverzani Thanks. Your example helped me piece together an example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, thanks to jverzani's link, I was able to piece together a working example. I'm still a little shaky on the syntax in Julia for setting all the options for the plot.

```
using PyPlot
using PyCall
@pyimport matplotlib.patches as patch

cfig = figure()
ax = cfig[:add_subplot](1,1,1)
ax[:set_aspect]("equal")
c = patch.Circle([0.5,0.5],0.4,fc="blue",ec="red",linewidth=.5,zorder=0)
ax[:add_artist](c)
cfig[:savefig]("circle.png")
```